# NullPointerException Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate Type: com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When I try to run native query, I am getting the below error when I try to run a `native query` in spring jpa. I've added the  dialect to custom dialect extended as

> spring.jpa.database-platform=com.config.HibernateCustomDialect

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.internal.AbstractArrayTypeDescriptor.setParameterValues(AbstractArrayTypeDescriptor.java:34) ~[hibernate-types-52-2.6.1.jar:na]
at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType.setParameterValues(StringArrayType.java:50) ~[hibernate-types-52-2.6.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.injectParameters(TypeFactory.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.type(TypeFactory.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

Below is my entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@TypeDef(
    name = "string-array",
    typeClass = StringArrayType.class
)
public class Session {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long sessionId;

   @Type(type = "string-array")
   @Column(columnDefinition = "text[]", name = "tags")
   private String[] tags = null;

   private long oId;

   // More Fields

}
```

Custom Dialect

```
public class HibernateCustomDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateCustomDialect.class);


    public HibernateCustomDialect() {
       super();
       log.info("Registering Custom Hibernate Dialect - {}",HibernateCustomDialect.class.getName());
       this.registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, StringArrayType.class.getName());
    }
}
```

Jpa Repository

```
@Repository
public interface SessionRepository extends JpaRepository<Session, Long> {
   String sessionSummaryViewQuery ="SELECT session.session_id, session.tags FROM public.session WHERE session.oid=?1"

   @Query(value =sessionSummaryViewQuery,nativeQuery = true)
   List<SessionSummaryView> findByOpportunityId(long opportunityId);//, Pageable pageable);


}
```

And my DTO :

```
public class SessionSummaryView {
    private Long sessionId;
    private String[] tags;
    private Long oid;


}
```

`StringTypeArray` is an implementation in the following library.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you add the code of `StringArrayType`?

Comment: It is in the library. Added the dependency

Comment: @sanemain, are you referring to `@TypeDef` in the Entity class? It's working fine, if I read entity, I am able to fetch Entity. But unable to get the POJO.

Comment: @Mansoor, yes I referred to the `@TypeDef` in the Entity class. The exception you get is caused by the following line of `AbstractArrayTypeDescriptor` class: `((ParameterType) parameters.get(PARAMETER_TYPE)).getReturnedClass();` I think the solution is to specify `String.class` as the parameter. I could not figure out how to do that yet.

Comment: Thanks. i'll try that

Comment: You might try something like:  `@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class, parameters = {@Parameter(name = "org.hibernate.type.ParameterType", value = String.class)}`

Comment: You may also want to try: `@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class, parameters = {@Parameter(name = "org.hibernate.type.ParameterType", value = "java.lang.String")}` or `@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class, parameters = {@Parameter(name = "org.hibernate.type.ParameterType.returnedClass", value = "java.lang.String")}`

Comment: @sanemain, No Luck.

Comment: @Mansoor, I noticed a closing paranthesis is missing at the end. Did you place it yourself while testing?

Comment: @sanemain, No Luck. I am able to debug the class StringArrayType but unable to identify what and how the value for Parameter be.

Comment: I think a similar problem is discussed at https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/issues/70 . The `@Type` also takes a list of `@Parameter` s, so you can also try to supply a parameter within `@Type`.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into the test cases for past 3 hours and didn't cross my mind to check issues or PR. I think I identified the solution. Cannot wait for the PR to be merged. I'll implement my `CustomType` extending the `StringArrayType`

Comment: Why would you extend `StringArrayType` though? In one of the comments from the previous link I provided, the library author posted this fragment as a solution: `<type name="com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType">            
     <param name="org.hibernate.type.ParameterType">MyCustomJsonObject</param>
</type>` I think `<type>` tag corresponds to the `@Type` annotation in your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through internet and scanning all the pages there related to hibernate, I found a workaround.

I implemented a `CustomStringArrayType` extending `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType`.

ref - https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/issues/142 I couldn't wait for PR to be merged so implemented the workaround as below:

```
public class CustomStringArrayType extends StringArrayType {

  @Override
  public void setParameterValues(Properties parameters) {

    if (parameters.containsKey(super.PARAMETER_TYPE)) {
        super.setParameterValues(parameters);

    }
  }
}
```

My modified HibernateDialect is as below:

```
public class HibernateCustomDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateCustomDialect.class);


  public HibernateCustomDialect() {
    super();
    log.info("Registering Custom Hibernate Dialect - {}",HibernateCustomDialect.class.getName());
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, CustomStringArrayType.class.getName());
  }
}
```